# How to enumerate non-isomorphic triangulation of convex polygon with n+2 sides?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, triangulation

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467733/how-many-non-isomorphic-ways-a-convex-polygon-with-n-2-sides-can-be-cut-into) answer it's possible to count how many non isomorphic triangulations correspond to a particular polygon.

I've also found [here](http://jgaa.info/accepted/2011/ParvezRahmanNakano2011.15.3.pdf) that there's the possibility to generate a tree containing every non isomorphic triangulation. So each node is associated with a triangulation. The goal is to access to a particular triangulation without generating the whole tree. Please note that I don't need to specify the particular structure of the triangulation: if the tree has 42 node and i want to access to 28th node I'd like to access to the node associate uniquely to it.

Anyway it's just one of the possible approach, all i need is an enumeration or a mechanism of uniformly at random choice of one of the triangulation.

Comment: So, you want a function from $[C_n]=\{1,2,\cdots , C_n\}$ to triangulations?

Comment: Hi Phicar, yes if possible. But also to access to the last element of the enumeration without generating every other element